# C++ No appropriate default constructor

Tags: c++

I know this has been asked before, but I can't find the problem on my code.
It's a fairly simple code, I have checked and the class `Point` works perfectly ( it has a default value of (0,0) ), though the `Circle` one isn't

```
 class Circle{
public:
    Circle(Point, double);
    Circle(const Circle& c);
    ~Circle();
    void setCenter(Point scenter);
    void setRadius(double sradius);
    double getSurface();
    Point getCenter() const;
    double getRadius() const;
    void print() const;

private:
    Point center;
    double radius;
};

Circle::Circle(Point c, double r)
{
    r = 1.0;
    setCenter(c);
    setRadius(r);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to implement a default constructor, meaning one without any parameters (or the parameters have default arguments) ... `Circle()`

Comment: The code is posted does not demand default constructor for Circle (which you do not have). It is perfectly fine to have a class without default constructor, but than it should not be used without specific constructor.

Comment: Only if you actually try to use the default constructor (as in `Circle circle;`), which isn't shown here

Comment: What is the error and on which line? Where is the definition of the `Point`?

Comment: You probably want `Circle(Point, double)` to be `Circle(const Point &, double)`, though it's not related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

A default constructor is only generated for you if you have no other constructors. If you want to have a default constructor (i.e., no arguments) in addition to constructors with arguments, you need to define it

Comment: +1, I should also add that at some point in your code you are attempting to do Circle foo;  or   Circle foo ();   or        Circle*  foo = new Circle();               thus invoking a no argument constructor. if you were to only use the constructors you defined, there would be no errors;